# How to modify this table?

Tags: tables

Below is the code I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|cc|cc|cc|cc|}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{O1}                      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{O2}       & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{O3} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{|c}{O1.1}     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{O1.2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{O2.1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{O2.2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{O3.1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{O3.2} \\
    \midrule
    Criteria 1.1.1 & Criteria 1.1.2 & Criteria 1.1.3 & Criteria 1.1.4 & Criteria 1.2.1 & Criteria 1.2.2 & Criteria 2.1.1 & Criteria 2.1.2 & Criteria 2.2.1 & Criteria 2.2.2 & Criteria 3.1.1 & Criteria 3.1.2 & Criteria 3.2.1 & Criteria 3.2.2 \\
    \midrule
    1     & 2     & 3     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

The table I generated is not clear, and it is as shown in the figure below.
[image]

I want the table to look like this. How can I modify this? If this table is too wide, it is also good to consider transposing the table; how to do that?

[image]

Comment: don't ignore error messages `! Undefined control sequence.
l.9     \toprule`  load `booktabs` not `tabularx`

Comment: Plus vertical lines does not play well (by design) with `\toprule` etc.

Comment: but never use `booktabs` with vertical rules

Comment: Two considerations: 1) Do you really need such a long word as "criteria" over and over again? Why not abbreviation to C 1.1.1 etc.? // 2) Why don't you write the table again, with rows and columns interchanged? (No, it's not Excel, which can transpose cells)

Comment: I enlarge of `\textwidth` by use `geometry` package an option?

Comment: Can you modify your question title to provide a more descriptive (yet essential) reference to what you're interested in? That is, not just state "How do I do this?"; elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Off-topic: "criteria" is a plural-form noun. Its singular-form counterpart is "criterion".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're committing one of the most frequent sins in tables, namely repeating information.

Since every column is about criteria, remove the repetition and use a single header encompassing all of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]

\centering
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{14}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{14}{c}{Criteria} \\
\cmidrule{1-14}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{O1} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{O2} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{O3} \\
\cmidrule{1-6} \cmidrule{7-10} \cmidrule{11-14}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{O1.1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{O1.2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{O2.1} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{O2.2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{O3.1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{O3.2} \\
\cmidrule{1-4} \cmidrule{5-6} \cmidrule{7-8}
\cmidrule{9-10} \cmidrule{11-12} \cmidrule{13-14}
1.1.1 & 1.1.2 & 1.1.3 & 1.1.4 & 1.2.1 & 1.2.2 & 
2.1.1 & 2.1.2 & 2.2.1 & 2.2.2 & 
3.1.1 & 3.1.2 & 3.2.1 & 3.2.2 \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With `\footnotesize` this is good enough for the standard page width, but this might not be the case for your actual table, depending on the data in it.

[image]

Vertical rules aren't necessary; actually they hinder readability. The horizontal rules tell the reader how columns are grouped.

Note. I placed the caption below the table, because this is the default for the standard classes. If you want it above the table, load the `caption` package or, at least, add some vertical space between caption and table.

Comment: +1. One (very minor!) nit to pick: Since the target width of the `tabular*` environment is set to `\textwidth`, the `\centering` instruction isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

- Your table is to wide thgan can be fit on page with default `article` layout.
- Options are

  - use `\small` font size and change page layout by use  of the `geometry` package accordingly
  - ust default pages layout, rotate table and use `small` font size
- In all case write column headers in two lines
- In the later case you can get:

[image]

For this table I would use  `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \caption{Add caption}
  \small
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{2-Y}, vlines,
             colspec = {*{14}{X[c]}},
             colsep  = 3pt,
                 }
\SetCell[c=6]{c}    O1
    &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    O2
                            &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    O3
                                            &   &   &   \\
    \SetCell[c=4]{c}    O1.1
    &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    O2.1
                    &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    O2.2
                            &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    O3.1
                                            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    O3.2
                                                    &                               \\
Criteria 1.1.1  & Criteria 1.1.2 & Criteria 1.1.3 & Criteria 1.1.4 
                & Criteria 1.2.1 & Criteria 1.2.2  
                & Criteria 2.1.1 & Criteria 2.1.2 
                & Criteria 2.2.1 & Criteria 2.2.2 
                & Criteria 3.1.1 & Criteria 3.1.2 
                & Criteria 3.2.1 & Criteria 3.2.2  \\
 1  & 2 & 3 &   &   &   &   &    &   &   &   &    &   &             \\
    \end{tblr}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```